# Cython: Passing a list of pointers to a worker function from a pool

Tags: cython

I would like to speed up the following Cython code. I am thinking in the line of having some pure C object of array of pointers for HugeList, which needs to go through a Python process-distribution to several instances of Worker function. HugeList is indeed huge and each array at particular index is moderately big. What could I improve in this fragment:

```
from cpython cimport array
import array
from bisect import bisect_right
from zlib import decompress

def StructureBuilder(fileHandle):
    HugeList = list()
    with open(fileHandle, "r") as IndFile:
        for line in IndFile:
            HugeList.append(array.array('I', (decompress(eval(line)))))
    return HugeList

def Worker(HugeList, unsigned long int index, unsigned int slice, unsigned int elem):

    Slot = HugeList[index][:slice]
    Position = bisect_right(Slot, elem)

    return Position
```

Comment: Unclear. Do you wantr to write a C module for your Cython code or just use Cython's features? In the latter case remove the C tag, as it is unrelated; Cython is not C.

Comment: I would like to cytonize the fragment indeed so I removed the C flag. My apologies.

Comment: It still is unclear what you are asking particularily. Please remember we are neither a coding nor tutoring service. As a sidenote: don't do premature optimisations. Profile if your code is not fast enough (and you exclused external influences, e.g. low RAM/swapping, etc. Also there are standard modules like NumPy which are often faster than hand-crafted code and provide more suitable types.

Comment: I would like to make from HugeList a C-style array of pointers, free of python bulk, which can be passed to a worker function.

Comment: Did you even read about NumPy??

Comment: `bisect_right` is implemented as pure Python code so can't efficiently be run in parallel, which is likely to limit what we can do with the code shown here (numpy might have a suitable alternative though)

Comment: @Olaf: I do not understand your hostility even if we assume that I was newbie with Python. I simply do not want to include yet another dependency of Numpy.

Comment: @DavidW: Is there any other alternative to bisect_right, which can be used in cython? How can I type an array of pointers for HugeList in the first function?

Comment: @Ivaylo If you don't want to use numpy then the alternative to bisect_right is to rewrite it yourself in Cython (probably using memoryviews for speed). I not change HugeList to be an array of pointers - it will turn into a memory management disaster and not get you as much speed as you think. Instead make `Slot` a memoryview and work on speeding up the operations applied to it.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Indeed the code above is not all, but this is the most critical. I passed a memoryview to bisect_right, but it made it slower (probably because of an overhead of create memoryview and then simple list to bisect). Would it be possible to make HugeList a memoryview in Worker?

Comment: There's no benefit to passing a memoryview to `bisect_right`. The benefit would be if you were able to rewrite `bisect_right` in Cython to take advantage of memoryviews. I don't think you could make `HugeList` a memoryview without numpy (Python has no built-in 2D array) and I don't really see the benefit of it.

Comment: To clarify - the benefit of a memoryview is that Cython can access their elements at much faster speeds than Python can access array elements. They aren't any faster if you pass them to Python functions like `bisect_right`

Comment: Thank you DavidW, you were right. I made my own cython-version (pure cdef) of a bisect-like function, typed Slot as memoryview and saw huge increase of performance. Unfortunately, Worker function is much more complex than that in the example :-), so I cannot make it more "cdef" (also it will always accept python-object, it seems). Thank you for your patience and help.